# Tailwind not rendering colors right on my Brave browser

Tags: tailwind-css, darkmode, brave-browser

**This image is from Chrome, notice the color of the `text-red-900`**
You can see the example output on the right side, the `Aa`.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color

[image: This image is from Chrome, notice the color of the text-red-900]

**This image is from Brave Browser, notice the color of the `text-red-900` is lighter than most of the other `text-red-xxx` classes.

[image]

Why is this? Both are using my computed system default `dark` mode.

You can see there is a inline style overriding the CSS color for this element, where is this inline style coming from? and how do I prevent it?
`--darkreader-inline-color: #e17d7d;`

[image]

**Note: I have 2 macbook pro Os Monterey M1s. This is only happening on one of them, the other is rendering colorrectly.**

Answer (score 1):

I completely uninstalled Brave Browser, including all the files for Brave within the `~/Library` folder like Preferences and what not.
Then I reinstalled, and seems to be working without any additional settings.

Is there some setting that would force elements to be lighter in Brave Browser to support Accessibility.

I believe it was some extension called [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh) that was brought over from chrome (disabled on chrome, but enabled on Brave) What an annoying extension.